# Unable to invoke adapter procedure

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I'm using IBM MobileFirst to create an app. I've created an HTTP Adapter and now I'm working on the invocation of the response within my main.js file. Here is the invokeProcedure call (the invocationData var calls the adapter and the procedure within that adapter):

```
    WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData,{
       onSuccess : loadSuccess(),
       onFailure : loadFailure(),
    });
```

Now, I've defined a loadSuccess() and a loadFailure() function (declared before the invocation) as such (simple for testing purposes):

```
    var loadSuccess = function(result){
       alert("success");
       alert(result.invocationResult);
    }

    var loadFailure = function(result){
       alert("failure");
       alert(result.invocationResult);
    }
```

However, while "success" and "failure" will flash, "result" is coming back as null. Every tutorial I have seen as used these methods with success, so I am confused as to why my similar implementation is not working. Furthermore, the invokeProcedure function seems to be calling and flashing the results of both the success and failure options!

My adapter returns an appropriate response when I just test that, so why isn't the invocation of the data working correctly? IBM documentation is not very clear, so I appreciate any and all suggestions!

EDIT:

I updated main.js to the following code:

```
    function loadSuccess(result){
      alert("success");
    }

    function loadFailure(result) {
      alert("failure");
    }

 function testFunc(userid, password) {
     var invocationData = {
        adapter : 'myAdapter',
        procedure : 'myProc',
        parameters : [ userid, password ],
    };

    WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData,{
       onSuccess : loadSuccess,
       onFailure : loadFailure
   });
}
```

When I test my adapter, by simply calling it, the response is successful and contains all the response information I want. So why isn't onSuccess being called here?

Comment: please provide the following : adapter code - authenticationConfig.xml - main.js

Comment: A link to the documentation for the auth config https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/authentication-security/adapter-based-authentication/

Answer (score 1):

Likely you need to remove the param brackets from the onSuccess and onFailure declarations, otherwise it runs the functions when assigned rather than when needed:

```
WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData,{
   onSuccess : loadSuccess,
   onFailure : loadFailure
});
```

Comment: I have tried this...when I remove the parentheses, the loadSucces and loadFailure functions are not called at all, so that the "success" alert and "failure" alert never even appear.

Comment: Alright, well I am fairly sure you don't want the brackets there since the functions don't return anything. I do not know what else might be wrong without more information.

Comment: Since the adapter lives on the server, I think the next thing you'd want to check is cross origin request security and be sure the server is configured for your test environment for port access.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using "var" to define your onSuccess/onFailure callbacks make sure they're in the same scope. Try providing inline callbacks, e.g.

```
WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationOptions, {
   onSuccess: function(data){ alert....},
   onFailure: function(data){ alert....}
})
```

Comment: Since he's seeing them 'flash' the alerts when using his original code, I think his scope is correct.

Comment: @Radio they're flashing because of brackets, as you've pointed out in your answer. I'd also advise using dev console to see if there are some JS exceptions thrown.

Comment: Thank you, I know they're flashing because of the brackets. They're also flashing because they're being found and so scope is not the issue. Rewriting them as lambda functions proves nothing. IMO he needs to look at security next. https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/authentication-security/adapter-based-authentication/

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare initOptions.js , main.js and messages.js in the html file that will use the controller that points to your adapter ..

else the invokeProcedure will be undifined

just go to your html file and but this code in the end of body tag directly before closing  tag

```
<script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="js/messages.js"></script>
```